# Pause and resume animations using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins

In our current project we have deployed animations of various objects using jquery. Can anyone suggest a method to pause and resume the animations.

We have heard about queue but was not able to do proper pause and resume.Please suggest how to  pause animations using queue.Please note that we have multiple objects and we need to pause all the animations on a button click and resume thereafter on another button click.

It would be kind of you if anyone can demonstrate or provide a example.
(Pause plugin didn't work as we have some delay functions in between our animations)

Comment: Removed the recommendation text. Reccommending off site resources is [off topic for SO](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 2):

Can be done easily using the `stop()` function.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/6eMQq/

**Code:**

```
// to animate or continue animation
$('#item').animate({width: '500px'}, 2000);

// to pause the animation
$('#item').stop();
```

Comment: We have multiple objects and their corresponding animations. please provide an example to pause all at once and then resume

Comment: Check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/6eMQq/1/ - It uses the `:animated` selector to identify objects being animated.

Comment: We cannot rewrite the code or provide functions while resuming.Also we require multiple objects with unique animations that needs to be paused and resumed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery `animate()` and `stop()` to-do start and pause animation,

`animate` - http://api.jquery.com/animate/

`stop` - http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Check out the jQuery Demo here,
http://jsfiddle.net/muthkum/KP74n/

Answer (score 0):

```
function animateLoop( $elem ){
    var i = $elem.data("i");
    var ti = 1 - i;
    var startPos = ( 2 * ti * contentWidth ) - contentWidth;
    $elem.css('margin-left', startPos + "px");
    $elem.animate( 
        { 
            'margin-left' :  - contentWidth + "px" },
        {
            duration: ( time * 1000 * ti ),
            easing: 'linear',
            step: function( v, p ){ 
                $elem.data( 'i', i + p.pos * ti ); 
                //console.log( i + p.pos * ti ); 
            },
            complete: function(){ 
                $elem.data( 'i', 0 ); 
                animateLoop( $elem ); 
            } 
        }
    );
};

$content.data('i',0);
animateLoop( $content );
```

My suggestion about how stop and resume jquery animate loops.